# The main memory is a volatile memory, how to ensure that data is not lost?

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I saw an introduction about write-through caching on the Internet.

> Write through is a storage method in which data is written into the
> cache and the corresponding main memory location at the same time. The
> cached data allows for fast retrieval on demand, while the same data
> in main memory ensures that nothing will get lost if a crash, power
> failure, or other system disruption occurs.

https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/write-through

But main memory is volatile storage. When there is a power failure, the data in the main memory cannot be recovered, so using write-through caching cannot guarantee that it will not be lost? This is inconsistent with the above introduction. May I ask how is this going?
Thanks

Comment: Surprise! Not everything on the Internet is correct. It seems that the page is using the term "main memory" to mean nonvolatile storage, which is not the commonly used meaning of the term.

Comment: This is an introduction of write-through caches. I think the main memory here should be clear.

Comment: You can do write-through caching for a disk cache, for NVRAM (like 3D XPoint / Optane DC Persistent Memory or just battery-backed DRAM), for example.  Normally you don't use WT caching for that because writes are slow, but you *could*.  So either this is just plain wrong, or the author forgot what they were talking about between sentences, or it's not about normal CPU caches.  Given their use of "main memory", I'd go with "wrong".